# Running python code exported from qt creator and converted to python using pyqt5

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qt-creator, pyqt5

I recently encountered this error after attempting to run my python script. In short, I simply don't understand how I've fed three arguments. I've included what I considered to be the most relevant snippets of code. Help is very appreciated. Thank you.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "DESeq_rpkm_gui.py", line 946, in 
>   disp = Ui_MainWindow()
>   File "DESeq_rpkm_gui.py", line 21, in **init**
>   self.setupUi(self,QMainWindow)
>   TypeError: setupUi() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

```
    class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
            self.setupUi(self,QMainWindow)

        def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
```

and

```
            if __name__=='__main__':
                app = QApplication(sys.argv)
                disp = Ui_MainWindow()
                disp.show()
                sys.exit(disp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a method as `object.method(argument1, ...)` then `object` is implicitly passed to the method as the first argument.

So with your current code, the line `self.setupUi(self,QMainWindow)` is actually passing three arguments to the method `setupUi`. They are `self`, `self` (again) and `QMainWindow`.

You might want to read this: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/1994235)

Now, you may have been confused by this because PyQt is a bit unorthodox in how you call/use the `setupUi` method. The documentation is [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) for your reference, but in short, they expect you to call `self.setupUi(self)`.

This is so that you can use the `setupUi` method to create your UI in any widget you pass in (or even more than one!). This is explained in the first example of the documentation:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from ui_imagedialog import Ui_ImageDialog

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()
ui = Ui_ImageDialog()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You are using what I consider the more conventional approach, and calling `setupUi` from within your `__init__` method. This is covered in the second example in their documentation, and should be called as I outlined above.